# How to use Vlc.DotNet in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to use VLC in WPF via Vlc.DotNet.  I have been successful in getting Vlc.DotNet to work in Winforms, but thus far unsuccessful with WPF.

I get no errors, but I also get no video...  just a blank white pane.

Here is my very simple XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="VLC.Wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Closing="Window_Closing">

    <Grid x:Name="Grid1">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is the codebehind I use to insert and start the Vlc Wpf control.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    VlcContext.LibVlcDllsPath = CommonStrings.LIBVLC_DLLS_PATH_DEFAULT_VALUE_AMD64;
    VlcContext.LibVlcPluginsPath = CommonStrings.PLUGINS_PATH_DEFAULT_VALUE_AMD64;

    VlcContext.StartupOptions.IgnoreConfig = true;

    VlcContext.Initialize();

    InitializeComponent();

    var vlcPlayer = new VlcControl();
    var media = new LocationMedia("rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.42.200:554/MediaInput/h264");

    Grid1.Children.Add(vlcPlayer);

    var vlcBinding = new Binding("VideoSource");
    vlcBinding.Source = vlcPlayer;

    var vImage = new Image();
    vImage.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, vlcBinding);

    var vBrush = new VisualBrush();
    vBrush.TileMode = TileMode.None;
    vBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
    vBrush.Visual = vImage;

    Grid1.Background = vBrush;

    vlcPlayer.Play();
}
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with this?

Using Vlc 2.1.5 win32

Comment: Have you looked at the WPF Example: http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Wpf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set vlcPlayer's `Media property`.

```
var vlcPlayer = new VlcControl();
var media = new LocationMedia("rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.42.200:554/MediaInput/h264");

vlcPlayer.Media = media; //add this
```

Btw, you don't need to add `vlcPlayer` to `Grid1`.

Comment: Doah!! I had intended to do this: vlcPlayer.Media = new LocationMedia("rtsp://etc etc     Sometimes you can't see what's right in front of you and need fresh eyes.

Comment: @cavedove (sic!): No, you ain't vlcPlayer.Media = ...
You only have var media = ...
So, technically speakin' KennyZX is right
Doah!! ;-)